# pygame window automatically exits after pygame.display.update(). How to prevent?

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code:

```
font=pygame.font.SysFont(None,80)
font.set_bold(True)
text=font.render('GAME OVER',False,RED)
textRect=text.get_rect()
textRect.centerx=mainSurface.get_rect().centerx
textRect.centery=mainSurface.get_rect().centery

mainSurface.blit(text,textRect)
pygame.display.update()
```

Before this snippet I have a loop which causes an animation. The loop exits and this code starts. After the execution I want to freeze the window so that Player can see 'GAME OVER' text until he closes the window. 
But unfortunately, the window automatically exits after few milliseconds after the text(`'GAME OVER'`) been displayed. **How to prevent the auto-closing without any extra code at the end?** I don't want to add another pygame.event.get() loop.
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: you can't stop it. You need loop or at least `time.sleep()` I prefer loop which checks mouse click (inside window) and ESC to exit (button closing window is too far for me).

Comment: BTW: see http://imgur.com/MT7tZ4s

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible.

Here is the documentation for pygame.display: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html

Under pygame.display.quit(), it says the following (emphasis added):

"
This will shut down the entire display module. This means any active displays will be closed. **This will also be handled automatically when the program exits.**

It is harmless to call this more than once, repeated calls have no effect.
"

As shown here, the Pygame window will close whenever the program exits.